# Почему изменяется значение слайса?

Tags: golang

Возник вопрос, связанный с изменением слайса при вызове метода структуры. В Go передается всё по значению, поэтому в методе должна быть копия слайса структуры, поэтому при любом изменении слайса внутри функции, как я понимаю, не должно быть никаких изменений для слайса самой структуры, так как работаем с копией. Однако в данном примере кода вместо вывода того же слайса получается следующее:

```
{[123 456 789]}
{[123 789 789]}
```

При изменении элемента, который как будто удаляется из слайса вывод также изменяется. Если выбрать 123, то будет следующий:

```
{[123 456 789]}
{[456 789 789]}
```

А при 789, такой:

```
{[123 456 789]}
{[123 456 789]}
```

Пример кода:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "slices"
)

type T struct {
    slice []string
}

type ArrayPointer struct {
    slice []string
}

func (t T) delete(elem string) {
    index := slices.Index(t.slice, elem)
    t.slice = slices.Delete(t.slice, index, index+1)
}

func main() {
    t := T{[]string{"123", "456", "789"}}
    fmt.Println(t)

    t.delete("456")

    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

Основной вопрос — почему вообще изменяется слайс и как связан найденный индекс элемента с выводом нового значения слайса? Полагаю, что изменяться слайс может из-за того, что он внутри также содержит указатель на память с элементами, но так до конца этот момент и не смог осознать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Коротко** методы, которые изменяют состояние объекта, нужно определять для указателя на тип: `func (t *T) delete(elem string)`. Такие методы оперируют непосредственно с объектом, для которого вызваны. Методы `func (t T)` оперируют с копией объекта.

Пруф: https://go.dev/play/p/Wau88dFOsIN

```
{[123 456 789]}
{[123 789]}
```

**Длинно**

Слайс - это структура данных из четырёх элементов:

- дескриптор типа элементов слайса,
- указатель на память, где лежат элементы слайса,
- число элементов в слайсе,
- максимальное число элементов, которые может вместить слайс.

Ваша функция `T.delete` принимает аргумент типа `T` по значению, то есть создаётся копия `t`, которая передаётся в функцию.

Внутри функции `delete` из слайса удаляется элемент, то есть происходит вот что:

- элементы от 0 до `index-1` остаются на своих местах,
- элементы от `index+1` до конца слайса копируются на одно место вперёд,
- число элементов в `t.slice` уменьшается на единицу.

Давайте рассмотрим первый случай. После удаления элемента `"456"` слайс `t.slice` в функции `T.delete` имеет вид `[]string{"123", "789"}`.

Новая память не аллоцируется, так как слайс не вырастает за пределы отведённой памяти. Это означает, что третий элемент исходного слайса остался в памяти. Когда функция `T.delete` возвращает управление, копия `t` уничтожается. Тот `t`, который в `main`, остаётся без изменний - его `t.slice` указывает на ту же область памяти, длина осталась той же - три элемента. Но функция `T.delete` изменила содержимое памяти, скопировав элемент `"789"` на место элемента `"456"`. Но сам элемент `"789"`, стоявший на третьем месте в исходном слайсе, остался на своём месте. Его никто не удалял. Поэтому он остался виден в слайсе `main::t.slice`

Аналогично во втором случае. При удалении элемента `"123"` элементы `"456"` и `"789"` были скопированы на первую и вторую позицию в памяти, но третий элемент остался в памяти, и остался виден в `main::t.slice`, так как в этом слайсе по-прежнему три элемента.

В третьем случае ничто никуда не копировали, в `T.delete::t.slice` уменьшили число элементов на 1. Но так как это копия слайса из `main::t`, то оригинал не изменился, и элемент `"789"` остался виден в `main`.

Поменяйте метод на `func (t *T) delete(elem string)`. Тогда `slices.Delete` будет оперировать непосредственно слайсом того объекта, для которого был вызван метод `delete`, а не с его копией.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Единстенный момент, который меня смутил в данном случае с копированием элементов от index+1, это как раз то, что при копировании не происходит удаления или замены последнего исходного элемента слайса, и он остаётся в памяти по-прежнему.

Comment: @eversince Так написано в документации: *Delete might not modify the elements s[len(s)-(j-i):len(s)]. If those elements contain pointers you might consider zeroing those elements so that objects they reference can be garbage collected.* Или посмотрите исходный код https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/exp/+/7918f672:slices/slices.go;l=219 . Там делают append, а это именно что копирование

Comment: Да, посмотрел исходный код и понял вас. Большое спасибо за полезную информацию!